# How do I get the html of a webpage using urllib?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm trying to get the href tags using BeautifulSoup and urllib for https://www.reddit.com/. This is my code;

```
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

searchurl = https://www.reddit.com/
html = urllib.request.urlopen(searchurl,context = ctx).read()
```

The above gives me the html in some instances however at other times it results in the following error;

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

How do I get the html in a consistent manner?

Comment: well the error tells you that you are trying to access a page you are not authorized to do so. Not much you can do there , except add some sort of authorization,

Comment: if it was unauthorized in terms of accessing the html, it wouldnt be giving the html in some instances while it doesnt give in other instances

Answer (score 1):

```
from urllib import request
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

searchurl = 'https://www.reddit.com'
html = request.urlopen(searchurl, context=ctx).read()

print(html)
```

This worked for me.
Try removing the trailing '/' from the url and be sure to surround the url with quotes